# ASP.NET Core Identity - Confirm email return url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've managed to set up SignUp and LogIn for my project with ASP.NET Core Identity. Everything works fine but there is a small thing really bugging me.

Since it is a simple project I don't want to configure account confirmation by really sending email to the user so I'm using the default templates, the user is redirected to the Account.RegisterConfirmation where they can select a link to have the account confirmed which redirects the user to the /Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail which is a blank page with the title only. I don't like it. After selecting a link to confirm the account I'd like to redirect the user to the /Account/Login. But where do I set that up?

This is what I've tried so far: Add>New Scaffolded Item>Identity>Account/ConfirmEmail(file to override) and I now I have ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public ConfirmEmailModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }

            code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
            StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Changing `return Page();` to `return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");` results in **InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Project.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ConfirmEmailModel'.**

Where do I set up the return url to /Account/Login after the email is confirmed?

I also tried without Scaffolding and overriding Account/ConfirmEmail, in Register.cshtml.cs there is

```
 var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

and I tried changing  `returnUrl = returnUrl` to `returnUrl = "~/Account/Login"` , it didn't work.

**** UPDATE ***

Since I don't need email confirmation for such a simple project I just added this

```
options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
```

to the Startup class so account confirmation nor email confirmation is needed.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectContext>();


services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
});
```

Comment: does it works fine for return Page();  I am seeing the error message is for the DI....

Comment: try adding a tilde '~' to the url like return RedirectToPage("~/Account/Login")

Comment: @RohitKumar I just noticed that it does not work for return Page() also, actually after  Add>New Scaffolded Item>Identity>Account/ConfirmEmail(file to override) I get  InvalidOperationException even if I do not make any changes to the ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it also doesn't work with ~

Comment: the error is with DI .....does the execution even reaches till **var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using the default templates, the user is redirected to the Account.RegisterConfirmation

In default code of configuring Identity service, we would find that `RequireConfirmedAccount` option is set to `true`, like below.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And we can find that user will be redirected to `RegisterConfirmation` page after user account is create in `RegisterModel` class page handler.

```
if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
{
    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
}
else
{
```

> it is a simple project I don't want to configure account confirmation

If you do not need account confirmation, you could not set
[**RequireConfirmedAccount** property (defaults to false) of **SignInOptions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1#properties) while you configure Identity service.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectContext>();
```

Or as you did, set [SignIn settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sign-in) explicitly.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectContext>();
```

Besides, we can find that you call `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(...)` to configure Identity service with your custom `ApplicationUser` class in Startup ConfigureServices method, but you inject an instance of UserManager within `ConfirmEmailModel` class using `UserManager<IdentityUser>` (should use `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`), which cause the exception.

[image]